# React Native navigation.navigate not working on headerRight button

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I face an issue when I click on header right button on navigation bar. 
I need to move next screen from headerRight button but I am getting **'undefined is not an object (evaluating _this4.props. navigation)'**.

Here is my code please check me and help me.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Setting')}
                style={{right: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
                       Dimensions.get("window").height < 667 ?  '10%' : '30%' : '25%', 
                       backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
                       paddingLeft: 15}}>
                <Image style={{width: 20, height: 20}} 
                       source={require('../assets/icons/setting/setting.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `navigation` as a prop in `navigationOptions`, so that will be available inside as `navigation` directly not with `this.props.navigation`.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Setting')}
                style={{right: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
                       Dimensions.get("window").height < 667 ?  '10%' : '30%' : '25%', 
                       backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
                       paddingLeft: 15}}>
                <Image style={{width: 20, height: 20}} 
                       source={require('../assets/icons/setting/setting.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
});
```